# Deleting all but the last 30 rows in database table with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple question. How can I delete all but the last 30 rows in a database table? For example, take the following query:

```
DELETE FROM Comments
WHERE got='$user_id'
```

What else do I need to do in order to keep the last 30 rows?

This is what the `Comments` table looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If your version if MySQL supports limits within sub-queries**, then you can use a sub-query that selects the 30 most recent rows. Then, you can delete everything except those rows which were found in the sub-query.

```
DELETE
FROM Comments
WHERE got='$user_id'
  AND got NOT IN
    (SELECT got
     FROM Comments
     ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 30)
```

**If your MySQL version does not support limits within sub-queries**, then you'll need to split it up into two separate queries:

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT got FROM Comments WHERE got='$user_id' ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 30
```

The results of query 1 should be stored in a single string variable (using the format `1,2,3...`) and passed into query 2. (The [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) functions may come in handy when formatting the string.)

**QUERY 2**

```
DELETE
FROM Comments
WHERE got='$user_id'
  AND got NOT IN ($formatted_result_from_query_1)
```

Comment: i was thinking to count all first then total -30 and delete rest in ASC order but i will try ur way its seems better

Comment: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' :)

Comment: Which version do you have running on the server?

Comment: Software: MySQL, Software version: 5.1.68-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL), Protocol version: 10 hosted on hostmaster.com

Comment: I've updated my answer to include older versions of MySQL. You'll need to split the query into two separate queries, storing the result of the first query as a PHP variable and passing it into the second query.

Comment: Thanks again so much this will surely help and i got already idea how to work with it now :)

Answer (score 2):

Store the last 30 rows in a temporary table and then exclude those rows from your delete:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS (SELECT id FROM Comments WHERE got="$user_id" ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5);

DELETE FROM Comments
WHERE got="$user_id" AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIMIT` to do so:

```
DELETE c1
FROM Comments AS c1
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT id 
   FROM comments
   WHERE got = ...
   ORDER BY id DESC
   LIMIT 30
) AS c2  
WHERE c2.id IS NULL;
```

See it in action here:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f308/1) (I just tried it with 5 rows only, with a simplified schema for your table)